# How to get a list of created GLX contexts for a process with command line

Tags: linux, command-line, x11, glx

I want to compare how apps are creating their GLX contexts.

I can easily check window info using `xwininfo` - this gives me e.g visual info, but nothing about OpenGL contexts.

Comment: Have you figured out how to list GLX clients? I'd like to use that to launch apps on the least busy GPU. (don't want to use NVIDIA-specific stuff)